# ValueError: unconverted data remains: 70

Tags: python, pandas

```
df['established_date']=[datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%d-%m-%y').strftime("%y-%m-%d") if not x=="nan" else x for x in df.established_date]
```

I am not getting why it is not working.

or

I am trying to convert `12-07-17` this date fromat to `2017-07-12` this format.

I have written above code but it isn't working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. When you have a problem processing a bunch of data, the first thing you should do is try to figure out which part of the data causes the problem. For this kind of conversion of a DataFrame column, it's easy, because each row is handled independently, so you just have to narrow it down to a row (cell, really) that causes the problem. Then you *read* the error message, and relate it to the problematic data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simpler method, that's designed for this, called [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df.established_date = pd.to_datetime(df.established_date, errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%d-%m')
```